# Kubectl config view gives empty results

Tags: kubernetes, configuration, config, kubectl, azure-aks

configuration is stored in ~/.kube/config. But when i use the below command it gives empty results.
 `kubectl config view`

Output:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

Comment: what info you get when you run this command `kubectl cluster-info dump`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Just to make sure, try running `kubectl config view --kubeconfig <PATH_TO_YOUR_CONFIG_FILE>`.
- Make sure your `$KUBECONFIG` is empty, (or that it points at `~/.kube/config`).
- If you installed `kubectl` via `snap` it might possibly be a sand-boxing issue.

Comment: This doesn't work. with with the explicit file, my yaml file has content under `users` yet user always comes up empty with with an explicit --kubeconfig and direct path

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same problem for a couple of days. The kubeconfig for my Linode cluster simply would not work. `kubectl config view -v 8` (verbose max) gave me this output:

```
I0312 10:01:07.513754   16368 loader.go:379] Config loaded from file:  C:\Users\username\.kube\config
apiVersion: v1
clusters: null
contexts: null
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: null
```

I finally discovered that my config file contained a zero width space (U+200B) at the beginning of one line. It was invisible in every editor I used, including Notepad++ with *show all characters* enabled. One of my colleagues found it using Vim. You can also find it by trying to convert the file to ASCII using iconv:

```
$ iconv -t ascii ./config
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
preferences: {}
iconv: config:4:0: cannot convert
```

Maybe an obvious thing to check for some, but it's not until you have experienced it. Copying the text into a new file brought it along invisibly as well.

I find it disappointing that kubectl will not at least provide an error message in this situation, instead of failing silently by outputting an empty kubeconfig. (I used kubectl v1.19.5 and v1.20.4).